# What is the meaning of the phrase "this side of x"? And how do I use it?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Since I don't understand it in the first place, I better just give you an example:

[Cracked.com example](http://www.cracked.com/article_20949_5-insane-petty-crimes-committed-by-north-korea.html), says *otherwise known as "the pettiest hobo crime this side of aggressive panhandling."* (**WARNING**: site graphics could be **NSFW**, YMMV)

It's not the only time I have seen it but it's the only one I can find via Google Search

The usage that I've seen seems to indicate some sort of comparison. The example above seems to say that "where we live, panhandling is aggressive", but I can't figure out the exact meaning

Note: So far I think I've only seen this phrase in cracked.com itself. Perhaps it's some kind of inside joke, but I certainly don't get it and its usage seems pretty legitimate

EDIT:
Mathias Foster gives 2 other examples: *this side of the black stump* and *this side of the equator*.

Comment: Other examples include 'this side of the black stump' or 'this side of the equator'. You may want to add these to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put them in. By the way, where have you heard such usage?

Comment: This is extremely common from where I come from (New Zealand) and is often used jokingly.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd say considering the nature of cracked.com (itself being a comedy site) its usage seems to be for a joke there, but how do you use it? What do you put on the 'x' part of the phrase? And what would that mean?

Comment: Hmmm... it is used as an exaggeration, as in 'the ugliest guy this side of Brazil' to show that this person is the ugliest person out of millions of people. Use anything you want as 'x' and think of it literally. If I was the fastest person this side of the front door, I am saying that I am the fastest person in the house.

Comment: It's now a snowclone. An early example, perhaps the founder member, is 'this side of the Mississippi'. Canis Lupus mentioned the fact that it's a type of idiom, but graciously deleted his answer on giving a straightforward link to [CDAI](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/this+side+of).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ah yes, I've heard of that one. IIRC that one sounds like it's used for something ridiculous that it blows the average occurrence out of the water, but I can't be sure

Comment: ... everything west of the Mississippi being vaster, grander, more abundant,  weirder, wilder – so the best beans / biggest silver mine / dryest land ... this side of the Mississippi. It goes without saying that it will be outdone on the other side.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm confused with the meaning you linked to. If I were to say "it's the biggest bean this side of Mississippi" does that mean the bean is indeed the biggest in Mississippi (it's just that there's an even bigger bean, but not located in Mississippi) or something else? Because that tfd definition of "other than something" would mean there is an even bigger bean located in Mississippi

Comment: Just read 'the Y-est X this side of a/the Z' to be a  humorous idiomatic way of saying 'a really Y X'. If you invent an example, make sure you don't mix comparators 'He's the best yod-dropper this side of the pond' but not 'the biggest goldmine this side of a Roman emperor'.

Comment: `this side --|some delimiter|-- other side even more so`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cracked.com is a satirical site, and their usage there is, appropriately to Cracked, inappropriate. Aggressive panhandling is very annoying; bilking nations out of tens of millions of dollars in taxes is a little bit worse than petty.

*This side of* is a common idiom, meaning *some (point/amount/quality) up to, but not including* another. [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/this+side+of) gives this example:

> Nobody *this side of* a Roman emperor wants athletes to die for the sake of entertainment.

*This side of heaven*, or *this side of the grave* are common examples of this idiom, as are *This side of (an age)*.

Dictionary.com gives it's origins in the 1400s, which I was doubtful, until I read this quote by Ben Johnson (1572–1637):

> For I loved the man and do honour his memory, on this side of idolatry, as much as any.

Comment: So the boundary metaphor pre-dates westward colonisation of the US.

Comment: So you're saying "this side of X" is basically "except X"?

Comment: There are two related senses now. The more obvious one is 'The biggest (etc) you'll find until you start looking at those on the other side of X'. There may be more than one that's bigger etc, which you'll come across when you expand your horizons. X is a notional horizon / boundary (the Mississippi, the black stump ...). The other sense is 'except for X [and his bigger brothers etc]': here, X is an arbitrary 'large' comparator (this side of Everest / the Queen Mary / a Roman emperor ...).

Comment: @Raestloz - yes, basically, but not "the other side of/more than" X. Edwin, yes, you're quite right.

Comment: @Raestloz "Except X" includes things that are beyond X, whereas "this side of X" does not.

Comment: @augurar upon further inspection, it looks like I missed the "this side of (an age)" example above

Answer (score 0):

In context, the full reference is:

> Yep, the country that may or may not be a nuclear power and that enjoys presenting itself as a legitimate player on the global stage is actively participating in cigarette counterfeiting and smuggling, otherwise known as "the pettiest hobo crime this side of aggressive panhandling."

[Cracked.com](http://www.cracked.com/article_20949_5-insane-petty-crimes-committed-by-north-korea.html)

The presented idea in this case is to make an argument that [cigarette counterfeiting](http://books.google.com/books?id=hjgFm_t1LE8C&lpg=PA41&ots=nXZtqK3vrs&dq=north%20korea%20counterfeit%20cigarettes&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=north%20korea%20counterfeit%20cigarettes&f=false) is a petty crime, and as the title of the Cracked page suggests, "Insane".

So, what's a petty crime? Basically, per Wikipedia's redirect, anything that would be considered a misdemeanor. From the link above, though, it seems that cigarette counterfeiting bilks "the U.S. federal government and state governments $736,000 (weighted average) in revenue for each 40-foot shipping container of illicit cigarettes entering the United States." This would likely be a [felony](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7201).

On one side, there's a large, thriving, business and on the other, there's poor people trying to make a few bucks. And the article's writer is trying to make a subjective point to say that the cigarette smuggling (implicitly, "and can you believe that's a *thing*?") is somewhat less of a *thing* than aggressive panhandling.

But what does that mean for the answer to the original question?

It means that the term *this side of* is simply a way of comparison. For this case, it reads that the left side is almost, but not quite, as important as the right side.